# llvm make copy without mapping

Tags: llvm

I'm making an optimization pass to replace existing function with duplicate function with one less argument. 
Duplicate function is made by initializing with Function::Create with one less argument, and using CloneBasicBlock to copy every block of existing function. Printing out seems to be fine, but "Referring to an argument in another function!" error is caused.

Document on CloneBasicBlock describes "The block returned is an exact copy of the specified basic block, without any remapping" which seems to be the cause, but I can't find the solution to the problem.

I tried to look through llvm documents on module, function, functionType, ValueMapper, and some others but couldn't get the answer. Making the module work as explicitly visible on printout is what I intend.

Below is the code after change obtained from F.getParent() printout, with error below. I'm converting use of call on @0 to @use_few_register.

[image: F.getParent()printout]

Below is the relevant part of the code

```
Value* arg1 = dyn_cast<Value>(F.getArg(0));
  Value* arg2 = dyn_cast<Value>(F.getArg(1));
  ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
  auto *I64Ty = Type::getInt64Ty(Context);

  vector<Type*> ArgTypes;
  ArgTypes.push_back(I64Ty);

  FunctionType *ftype = FunctionType::get(F.getFunctionType()->getReturnType(), ArgTypes, false);
  Function *func = Function::Create(ftype, F.getLinkage());
  func->copyAttributesFrom(&F);
  func->takeName(&F);
  F.getParent()->getFunctionList().push_back(func);

  for (auto &Arg : func->args()){
    Arg.setName("merged"); //testing on one Arg only
  }

  for (auto &BB : F){
    auto *clone = CloneBasicBlock(&BB, VMap);
    func->getBasicBlockList().push_back(clone);
  }

  Instruction* X = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::AShr, func->getArg(0), ConstantInt::get(func->getArg(0)->getType(), 32), "tmp1");
  Instruction* Y = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::And, func->getArg(0), ConstantInt::get(func->getArg(0)->getType(), 4294967295), "tmp2");
  Instruction* X_trunc = CastInst::Create(Instruction::Trunc, X, arg1->getType(), arg1->getName());
  Instruction* Y_trunc = CastInst::Create(Instruction::Trunc, Y, arg2->getType(), arg2->getName());

  Y_trunc->insertBefore(&func->getEntryBlock().front());
  X_trunc->insertBefore(Y_trunc);
  Y->insertBefore(X_trunc);
  X->insertBefore(Y);

  return func;
```

Any advice or suggestion on relevant document/ approach would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that CloneBasicBlock does precisely what its name suggests, and you want something slightly different: You want a clone that is identical in most respects, but different in two: When the original refers to an argument or basic block in the original function, you want the clone to refer to an argument or basic block in the copy.

Your best option is perhaps to look at how CloneBasicBlock() is implemented and write something like it, but with an extra loop that calls `getOperand()` to consider each operand of each instruction, and does `if(isa<Argument>(…){…} elsif(isa<BasicBlock>(…){…}` to treat those appropriately. You'll probably also need [slightly special treatment of phi nodes](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html#a8ce0c4746a1ec805e66409d20ae93922).